# Are there any spirits that equips either a Hammer or Golden Hammer?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Just got a 3-star mario spirit that's special ability is "increases duration of hammer/golden hammer usage".

That said, I have yet to see a single spirit offer such a powerful item for free. I've seen Ore Club spirits and Beam Sword ones, just not ones with hammer/golden hammer.

Does this even exist? If so, what's the point of bothering with this spirit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, there is no Spirit that equips a Hammer

To complement [Toomai's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/348516/222207) for completeness, you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and search through the full list of all 1303 Spirits [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/switch/234547-super-smash-bros-ultimate/faqs/76692/spirit-list) for "hammer."

Doing this, you'll find several Spirits that give "Weapon Attack ↑," which includes increasing Hammer power. You'll also find the Spirit you have, Mini Mario & Hammers, which increases the duration of Hammers.

However, it seems those are the only Spirits that have anything to do with Hammers. As of now at least, there is no Spirit that will let you start with a Hammer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes indeed, the Hammer and Golden Hammer are apparently strong enough items that not only is there no spirit that provides one at the beginning of matches, but the only spirit that touches them (specifically) at all is the singular "Mini Mario & Hammers" enhanced spirit. As a result, the only way its effect will be used is when a hammer happens to appear and you grab it. This makes the effect situational to matches where you know hammers are an active item.